# C++ function pointer casting

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I'm developing a templated binary search tree in C++ for a data structures class right now. Everything has been going well until now. This issue deals with some nitty gritty C++ stuff that I'm not to familiar with, and I need help.

I've previously defined functions that traverse the tree and visit each node in different orders. The one in question here is defined as follows.

TreeNode.h

```
public:
  static void PostOrderVisit(TreeNode<T>* node, void visit(const T& v));
```

TreeNode.cpp

```
template <class T> void TreeNode<T>::PostOrderVisit(TreeNode* node, void visit(const T& v)) {
  if (node->leftChild != NULL)
    PostOrderVisit(node->leftChild, visit);
  if (node->rightChild != NULL)
    PostOrderVisit(node->rightChild, visit);
  visit(node->value);
}
```

This works fine in a test program that makes nodes and statically calls PostOrderVisit.

In a friend class (BinSTree.h/cpp), I am implementing a method that deletes every node in the tree, so I thought it would be a good idea to use this visitor and call my Delete() function on each node (the Delete() function also works fine in test programs for the BinSTree).

This function is defined as follows.

```
template <class T> void BinSTree<T>::ClearTree() {
  TreeNode<T>::PostOrderVisit(this->root(), &BinSTree<T>::Delete);
}
```

And here lies the problem. g++ says...

```
BinSTree.cpp:156: error: no matching function for call to ‘TreeNode<int>::PostOrderVisit(TreeNode<int>*, void (BinSTree<int>::*)(const int&))’
TreeNode.cpp:56: note: candidates are: static void TreeNode<T>::PostOrderVisit(TreeNode<T>*, void (*)(const T&)) [with T = int]
```

In this case, I thought that `void (BinSTree<T>::*)(const T&)` would be an instance of `void (*)(const T&)`, but it is not. The only way I can get the call to be recognized by the function definition is by casting the function pointer like this:

```
TreeNode<T>::PostOrderVisit(this->root(), (void (*)(const T& v)) &BinSTree<T>::Delete);
```

This recognizes the function and calls it appropriately, however (this took some significant research...), C++ member functions have an implicit parameter that allows the 'this' keyword to be accessed from within. Casting a member function pointer to a plain function pointer drops the 'this' reference altogether, causing my Delete() method to seg fault (it uses 'this' quite a bit).

This has been a HELL of a hassle, and I have spent quite a bit of time on such a small bit of this project. Can anyone show me a way to either A: make the function be recognized without the casting, or B: how to maintain the 'this' reference throughout the cast. The ClearTree() and Delete() methods are both within the same class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're already using templates, skip function pointers and go directly to functors.  Non-virtual, non-function pointer calls can be inlined.  Make `visit` a template that can overload `operator () ()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-static methods take an implicit parameter for "this". E.g. for a method C::f(int i), you can think of it like f(C* this, int i). Any casting that you do and screws up this signature you can expect badness to happen. You have already experienced crashes but more sinister artifacts could make the program misbehave or crash at other seemingly random places.

You can use pointer to member function like this:

in .h

```
template <class C>
static void PostOrderVisit(C* node, void (C::* visit)(const T& v));
```

in .cpp (actually if it is a template it has all to be in h, otherwise link error)

```
template <class T>
template <class C>
void TreeNode<T>::PostOrderVisit(C* node, void (C::* visit)(const T& v))
{
    // ...
    T value;
    (node->*visit)(value);
    // ...
}
```

You either pass pointer to your derived class (C as in here) or pointer to base class (TreeNode as in original). At some point you may need to cast.

You can also leave original function for when you pass a normal function as visitor. Function overload would take care.

A more generic way can be to use std::function. Although it may have some minor performance hit it would be most generic.

e.g. (have not compiled may have some minor syntax errors):

```
static void PostOrderVisit(TreeNode<T>* node, std::function<void (const T& v)> visit);
```

Inside PostOrderVisit you just do visit(value), e.g. call like normal function.

When you call PostOrderVisit you can use all the power of std::bind or boost::bind to carry as much extra info as you wish. E.g.

PostOrderVisit(this->root(), std::bind(&BinSTree::Delete, this));

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `PostOrderVisit` should take the function argument as a pointer, i.e. `PostOrderVisit(TreeNode<T>* node, void (*visit)(const T& v))`.

However, that wont solve your problem because you are passing it a non-static member function. Either the function you pass to it has to be `static` in the class, or you can use something like [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) instead of a function pointer argument, i.e. `PostOrderVisit(TreeNode<T>* node, std::function<void(const T&)> visit)`.

**Edit**
In that case I think you have two ways you can do this: One is to change your design to fit the parameter, that means you can not use member methods as a parameter. The second is to change the code to fit your design, and explain to the teacher that you had to change the interface due to its limitations, and explain those limitations.

The problem with using a normal function pointer as argument is that member functions have an implicit and hidden argument, `this`, for the instance of the class. Normal functions do not have this hidden parameter, and so the compiler prohibits you from using a member function. The solution is to either use normal functions, which is not very C++-ish, another is to use `static` member functions (as they don't have a `this` pointer), or use something like `std::function`.

As for how to use `std::function`, you use it in the declaration and definition of `PostOrderVisit` like I've shown. When you call it you do something like this:

```
template <class T> void BinSTree<T>::ClearTree() {
    TreeNode<T>::PostOrderVisit(this->root(), std::mem_fn(&BinSTree<T>::Delete));
}
```

Comment: Not sure how much leadway I have to change the parameters PostOrderVisit takes, since it's a school project (a very terribly outlined one). Can I use std::function where the function is called? Or must it be in the declaration of PostOrderVisit? Sorry, I'm still a bit new to C++.

Comment: @JayElrod Added some explanations to my answer.